# Error: 's' does not name a type

Tags: c++

That is the error the code gives me, and I can't figure out why. It says the error occurs on the second to last line, or the end of the introStory function. (I am writing this in the parenthesis right now because is said my post is mostly code and I need to add more detail.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "windows.h"
using namespace std;

string classChooser();
string nameChooser();
void introStory(string position, string name);

int main()
{
    string charPosition = classChooser();
    cout << "You chose " << charPosition << " as your class.";
    string charName = nameChooser();
    introStory(charPosition,charName);

    return 0;
}

string classChooser()
{

    string position;
    while(true)
    {
        cout << "Choose a class wisely... \n\n";
        cout << "\tWarrior: \n\t  Health:75\n\t  Attack:25\n\n";
        cout << "\tWizard: \n\t  Health:25\n\t  Attack:75\n\n";
        cout << "\tRogue: \n\t  Health:50\n\t  Attack:50\n";

        cout << "\nWhich class do you want to select? : ";
        cin >> position;
        if(position == "wizard" ||position ==  "warrior" ||position ==  "rogue" ||position ==  "Wizard" ||position ==  "Warrior" ||position ==  "Rogue")
        {
            system("cls");
            return position;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n\nMake sure you typed in the word correctly, and used appropriate capitalization.";
            Sleep(3200);
            system("cls");
            continue;
        }
    }
}

string nameChooser()
{
    string name;
    cout << "\nPlease choose a name for your hero: ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << "\nYour name is now " << name;
    return name;
}
void introStory(string position, string name)
{
    cout << "\nLet the story begin...";
    Sleep(2100);
    system("cls");
    cout << "Once upon a time in a poor village, a young kid named " << name << " was digging a hole.";
    Sleep(4000);
    cout << "After digging for a couple hours he came across a chest.";
    Sleep(3200);
    string weapon;
    if(position == "Warrior" || position == "warrior")
        weapon = "sword";
    else if(position == "Wizard" || position == "wizard")
        weapon = "wand";
    else
        weapon = "dagger";
    cout << "When he opened it, he found a " << weapon;
    Sleep(2000);
    cout << "That was exactly what he had been wanting for the past couple of months.";
    Sleep(3000);
    cout << "You see, " << name << " wanted to be a " << position;
    Sleep(2700);
    cout << "So a " << weapon << " was the perfect choice.";
    Sleep(2100);
    cout << "With his new " << weapon << " he could finally explore the dark cave his father was lossed in.";
    Sleep(4000);
    cout << "He could slay the monsters in there everyone was so terrified of.";
    Sleep(3200);
    cout << "He headed toward the cave.";
    Sleep(2000);
}
```

Comment: Post less code which reproduces the error.

Comment: [Not reproducible](http://rextester.com/WRA39241).

Comment: I dont know what bit of code causes the error. @user93353

Comment: can you post error message from compilation log?

Comment: Which compiler/IDE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

That code, when entered *exactly* as is into MSVC++ Express 2010 (Win32 Console app, no precompiled headers), works perfectly.

Therefore, I suspect you either have a problem elsewhere (other code in your project, corrupted header files, a host of other possibilities), or you haven't posted the code that's causing the problem.

The `'s' does not name a type` error usually shows up when you use `s` where a type name is expected. That isn't the case with the code you've shown.

---

By the way, if you're *not* using Microsoft's compilers for Windows code, you need to specify that. It may be that the likes of MinGW et al are not so well integrated as Visual C++.